# No output while scraping using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I was going to scrap the commentary from espncricnfo website using scrapy and i got output(items.csv) as blank. These are my files.

**cricinfo.py (Spider File)**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from crictest.items import CrictestItem


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "cricinfo"
    allowed_domains = ["espncricinfo.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2014/engine/match/763595.html?innings=1;view=commentary/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//td[@class="battingComms" and b]')
        for row in rows:
            item = CrictestItem()
            item['overnum'] = row.select('b/text()').extract()[0]
            item['overnumtext'] = row.select('b/following-sibling::text()').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

**items.py**

```
 import scrapy

    class CrictestItem(scrapy.Item):
        overnum = scrapy.Field()
        overnumtext = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your xpath

you can try using this in chrome:
$x('//*[@id="commInnings"]/div[2]/div/div')

in your code rewrite the code in:
rows = hxs.select('//td[@class="battingComms" and b]')
i can't get any output in the console